# Unable to create local group CREATE OWNER

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, user-groups

I would like to create a local group named

```
CREATOR OWNER
```

to work around a bug that's mentioned [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21286).

However, when I use the commandline and type

```
net localgroup CREATOR OWNER
```

or

```
net localgroup (CREATOR OWNER)
```

I get the error

```
System error 1376. This local group doesn't exist.
```

What might be the error and how could I solve this?

Comment: Neither of those commands create a user group.  http://www.windowscommandline.com/net-localgroup/

Comment: You also need quotes if the user group name has a space in it.

Comment: @Ramhound Would I need a user group or a local user group? Or is the command "localgroup" wrong? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You are attempting to create a local user group since you are not connected to an AD domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create a local group named *Creator Owner*

The correct syntax would appear to be:

`net localgroup "Creator Owner" /add`

I make that statement based on the fact the following website indicated the following.

> The following example adds a local group called Exec to the local user
>   accounts database:
>
> `net localgroup exec /add`

What you attempted to do, would have displayed the currents users in the local group "Creator Owner" if it existed.  You also had a syntax error, so I went ahead and corrected it, to explain the message you received.

`net localgroup "CREATOR OWNER"`

> System error 1376. This local group doesn't exist.

[Net Localgroup](http://www.windowscommandline.com/net-localgroup/)